# Zero object in a preadditive category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, additive-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a category such that for each $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ the Hom-set $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is given the structure of an abelian group. We require that the composition law for morphisms is bilinear with respect to this group structure, but I don't think it will be relevant for this question. There are two axioms which we may impose on $\mathcal{A}$:

(ii) There exists an object $0\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}(0,0)$ is the trivial group.

(ii)' There exists an object $0\in \mathcal{A}$ such that for all objects $A\in \mathcal{A}$ the groups $\operatorname{Hom}(A,0)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(0,A)$ are trivial.

Is it possible to prove that (ii) implies (ii)' without using the Yoneda lemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\text{Hom}(0,0)$ is the trivial group, then the only arrow of $\text{Hom}(0,0)$ must simultaneously be the zero morphism and the identity morphism. Now for $f : A \to 0$, $$f = id_0 \circ f = 0_0^0 \circ f = 0_A^0$$ writing $0_A^B$ for the zero morphism from $A\to B$. The last equality is by bilinearity. The $g : 0 \to A$ case is completely symmetrical.